# How to remove the background when clicking on the text of a link?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Text widget with a link to another screen, when clicked, the background appears. How do I remove the background when clicked?
More in the photo

```
Align(                            
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
    child: FlatButton(
    //color: Colors.redAccent,
    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return new SettingPage();
    }
    ),
    ),           
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
    child: Row(
      
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child:SvgPicture.asset(iconSvgS5, height: 30.0, color:Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FaqPage()),
          ),
          child:Text(
            "Вопросы и ответы", 
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0
            ),                            
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ), 
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: just a text widget doesn't show any feedback when clicked, thats a button i guess, post the code

Comment: added code on question

Comment: above code simply put will never render a feedback when tapped, theres might be parent widget which is rendering the feedback?

Comment: delivered all this code, can you see the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wrapping your text widget inside of a button then the button by default have feedback to let users know when they are pressed, if you don't need the feedback consider wrapping the button with a `GestureDetector` widget, and passing a function to the `onTap` property

Comment: as I have told you you have a GestureDetector inside a FlatButton widget, FlatButton is producing the Feedback, and GestureDetector inside FlatButton doesn't make any sense, as I can see you are trying push a screen SettingsPage using parent, and FAQ screen using GestureDetector! which is child of flatbutton why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Removed the background color on click with this code:

```
splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hoverColor` property of the `FlatButton` to set the hoverColor to your liking, here is the modified code that disables the `hoverColor` (simply sets it to transparent `Colors.transparent`) -

```
    Align(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
      child: FlatButton(

        //setting the hover color to transparent.
        hoverColor : Colors.transparent,

        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return new SettingPage();
          }),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(iconSvgS5,
                  height: 30.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FaqPage()),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Вопросы и ответы",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Also side note having a `GestureDetector` inside of a `FlatButton` is redundant, and in your case it is ambiguous as well since they are do two separate navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Set all color properties of the FlatButton to `transparent`.
The example below also includes a convenient hack, how to make the clickable area wider, so if the user will press near the icon, the button will work.
It improves button responsiveness.

Example

```
FlatButton(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  minWidth: 24,
  onPressed: () => Get.back(),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(
        CupertinoIcons.clear,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.pureBlack,
        size: 18,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```